# Artifacts name in artifactory

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I am new to devops world. I recently build Jenkins pipeline for maven build and stored my artifacts on the oss Artifactory. I used artifactory plugins on the Jenkins pipeline code. All works correctly except, artifacts name & minor version. Artifacts correctly generated on the local jenkins system. However, while uploaded into artifactory, name came with major version number only.

Example : Artifacts on the local jenkins

abcd-v5.0.0-alpha.102.a39886b-distribution.zip

Artifacts on the artifactory:

abcd-5.0-distribution.zip

Basically "v5.0.0-alpha" come from git tags. How should get the same on the artifactory?

Jenkins code used:

````
def server = Artifactory.server "artifactory"
          def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
          def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
          rtMaven.tool = '3.6.3'
          rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: 'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot-local'
          buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'abc/pom.xml', goals: "clean install -Passemble -Dlicense.skip=true"
          buildInfo.env.capture = true
          buildInfo.name = 'build'
          server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo ```
````

Comment: You have to set the version in the version tag of your pom file accordingly to `<version>v5.0.0-alpha</version>` which I don't recommend because the prefix `v` is not really a good idea for a version better is `<version>5.0.0-alpha</version>` instead...also why not letting Maven deploy the artifacts via `mvn clean deploy` and why do you need a profiles `-Passembly`?

Answer (score 0):

Do let us know whether is it feasible for you to pass the details in the pom.xml file?

If yes, then for example I have configured the pom.xml file as below:

```
<groupId>org.jfrog.test</groupId>
<artifactId>multi</artifactId>
<version>3.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

and the artifacts getting deployed with repository-path "*/org/jfrog/test/multi1/3.7-SNAPSHOT/multi1-3.7-20210805.113313-6-sources.jar*" as shown in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Qzy.png)